# Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{}' error on my Angular App

Tags: angular

in my Angular Frontend I have environment.ts like this
~~~~~~`

```
export const environment = {

    production: false,
    apiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
};
```

and my data.service.ts like this

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  registerUser(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/register/', data);
  }
}
```

but when I try to run the project it is encountrd following error msg

```
Error: src/app/service/data.service.ts:17:39 - error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.

17     return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/register/' data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons can be that all the `environment` do not have the same property names.

Another workaround for this issue, is by assigning any type. Like shown below

```
return this.http.post((environment as any).apiUrl+'/api/register/' data);
```

Comment: it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. https://stackblitz-starters-9l8rvp.stackblitz.io
You need to import your object in the class you want to use it in.

`import { environment } from './environment';`

Comment: I have import in data.service.ts as `import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't recognize the apiUrl property on the environment object. This issue could arise if TypeScript is not able to infer the type of the environment object. To resolve this, you can explicitly specify the type of environment to avoid type-related errors.

Approach 1

```
export interface Environment {
  production: boolean;
  apiUrl: string;
}

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
};
```

OR

Approach 2

```
import { environment as env } from 'path-to-your-environment-file';

export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    registerUser(data: any) {
        return this.http.post(env.apiUrl + '/api/register/', data);
    }
}
```

Comment: same error here